# scikit learn random forest gives relative bad prediction

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit-learn to predict stock exchange direction using random forest and random tree classifiers. My features are indicators like simple moving average. My problem is that I'm getting relative bad predictions (roughly 50%) for both algorithms with default parameters. How can I improve that accuracy? Code is below:

```
    X = data_from_csv[['RSI', 'CCI', '5SMA', '10SMA', 'ROC', 'Momentum',  '%K', '%D']].astype(np.float32)
    y = data_from_csv['Direction1'].astype(np.float32)

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)
    rf = RandomForestClassifier()
    rf.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_pred = rf.predict(X_test)

    print metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred), 'train/test split random forest'

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)
    rt = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
    rt.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_pred = rt.predict(X_test)

    print metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred), 'train/test split decision tree'
```

Comment: do not use default parameters, tune them.... ML is not algorithmics, you can not "just run" algorithm and expect it to solve the problem.

Comment: I have tried setting parameters from like n_estimators for values in range of 10-200, didn't help

Comment: 10 fold cross validation also, but results aren't improving

Comment: provide a minimum reproducible example (data), otherwise noone will be able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely scenario is that your training data does not have great predictive value. Given that you're attempting to "predict stock exchange direction", this shouldn't be surprising since that problem is kind of impossible to solve.